# Hide messages marked for follow up until due date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to duplicate Google's Inbox "Snooze" feature using follow up flags in Outlook.

[image]

**What `field`, `condition` and `value` would I use to only show messages flagged for follow up, where the date is today or has already passed?**

Keep in mind that it should also show messages *not* flagged for follow up at all, but I don't really see a way to do `OR` on this interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing, this seems to accomplish the goal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the SQL DASL Filter:

"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/81040040" <= today(0)
OR 
NOT "urn:schemas:httpmail:messageflag" > 0

[image]

Reference:

[Doing more with Outlook filter and SQL DASL syntax](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewdelin/2005/05/10/doing-more-with-outlook-filter-and-sql-dasl-syntax/)

[Setting FollowUp statuses using MAPI](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94783892-937f-4f81-9feb-5d8e62e5e938/setting-followup-statuses-using-mapi?forum=outlookdev)